# Characterization of inverse limits of finite-dimensional convex cones

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convexity, limits-and-colimits, choquet-theory

Consider a countable inverse system $C_1\substack{f_1 \\ \leftarrow} C_2 \substack{f_2 \\ \leftarrow} C_3 \substack{f_3 \\ \leftarrow} \ldots$ where the $C_i$ are finite-dimensional convex cones of the form $[0,\infty)^{n_i}$ with $n_i\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ (that is, finite products of rays) and the $f_i$ are linear maps (affine maps sending $0$ to $0$). Is there a characterization of the possible inverse limit cones $\substack{\lim\\ \leftarrow} C_i$ that can occur? A couple of observations:

- I believe one can show that if the $f_i$ don't send any positive-dimensional faces to $0$ then the inverse limit $\substack{\lim\\ \leftarrow} C_i$ has a base which is a compact, metrizable Choquet simplex. Moreover, every compact, metrizable Choquet simplex appears as the base of some such inverse limit. So the difficult case is really when the $f_i$ send some faces to $0$.
- When the $f_i$ send some faces to $0$ it's possible to get an inverse limit $\substack{\lim\\ \leftarrow} C_i$ which doesn't have a compact base (for instance, it's possible to have $\substack{\lim\\ \leftarrow} C_i=\Pi_{i=1}^\infty [0,\infty)$, an infinite product of rays).
- The inverse limit is well-capped.

I realize that the word "characterization" is slightly vague. However, there is a characterization for inverse limits of finite-dimensional *simplices* which is easy to state: the inverse limits are always compact, metrizable Choquet simplices. See:

*Davies, E. B.; Vincent-Smith, G. F.*, [**Tensor products, infinite products, and projective limits of Choquet simplexes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10879), Math. Scand. 22, 145-164 (1968). [ZBL0176.42802](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0176.42802).

So one would ideally hope for a similarly clean characterization of the cones $\substack{\lim\\ \leftarrow} C_i$.